# Multiple threads unable to share common refresh token in Java Spring OAuth2

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

I have a Java application that is running within the Spring 3.x framework and utilizes the off-the-shelf Spring OAuth2 implementation (JDBC persistence).  My application exposes a REST interface that will be used by partners.  Those applications will have a variable number of threads all hitting my application.  'Variable' is the key thing here.  Ideally, I would like a *single* refresh token to be used per partner (in this case, the partner is the end user; they are not working on behalf of a common 'user').  What I am finding, however, is that if thread A requests an access_token from my server, token_A is returned.  That is fine, but if thread B then requests a token, token_A is invalidated and token_B is returned.  This obviously breaks thread A.

I have read through the RFC and I do not readily see that a second call to obtain an access_token should automatically issue a new token versus returning an existing, but still valid, token.  This is actually how the 'implicit' grant_type flow works, but not the 'refresh_token' grant_type flow.  I have pulled the GitHub source for DefaultTokenServices and it seems like the behavior is immutable and, I guess, desired.  So, I have two questions:

1. Is issuing a new token (and therefore invalidating an older one) both mandatory and desired?
2. How to I get myself out of this problem?  There *must* be multiple scenarios where multiple threads are sharing a single refresh_token. How do they work?

The ideal flow, as I see it would be something like this:

1. Thread A requests a token. None is found so a new token is created/returned. Validity period is 10 minute.
2. Thread A starts its processing, something that requires multiple requests and will take 8 minutes to complete
3. Thread B requests a token 7 minutes later. The token issues in #1 is still valid so that is returned; this token is now valid for 3 more minutes.
4. Thread B starts its procession, something that will take 5 minutes and multiple requests to complete
5. Three minutes into thread B's processing, target will return a 'not authorized' when the token granted in #1 expires. Thread B has 2 more minutes worth of processing to complete
6. Thread B requests a new token, which will be granted and which will be valid for 10 minutes
7. Thread B finishes the last 2 minutes worth of processing using the new token.

Comment: From what I just [read](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en) it sounds like that your partners would have to manage tokens, not you. And if they can't manage to share the token accross threads they would need different refresh tokens per thread. Otherwise cache token keyed on refresh_token and use that instead of generating a new one,

Comment: Yes, making the partner manage the tokens is a valid approach that I considered, but this means every partner will need to implement essentially identical code.  Not good.  So, if the RFC does not prevent returning an 'active' token, that is a superior way to go, IMHO.  Thank you for the response though! :)